# <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script> Breaks my Site, but I need for Event Tracking

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, events, google-analytics

I need Jquery to do event tracking for certain plugins. I get everything to work with the following:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
```

&

```
$('.home .et_pb_more_button').on('click',function() {
ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'click', 'case study');
});
```

Problem...the jquery code breaks the functionality of the website. How can I track events in Google Analytics, but not break the jquery functionality?

the site is directiveconsulting.com

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: I'll bet that somewhere else in your site you're already importing an older version of jQuery along with some old script that won't work with a newer version. *edit* ... and it's a real pain to tell from "view source" because the entire page is on one line. Find the problem in the original source, whatever it is.

Comment: Hmm...I will remove minify so you can view.

Comment: The greater problem is that <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script> breaks funcitonality

Comment: `breaks funcitonality` is pretty meaningless...what errors are thrown? Is jQuery included in page more than once?

Answer (score 1):

WordPress usually loads in jQuery automatically for the admin side of things among other things.

Try using jQuery in `noConflict` mode or calling the function using `jQuery` instead of `$`

```
jQuery('.home .et_pb_more_button').on('click',function() {
    ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'click', 'case study');
});
```

Read here about `noConflict`: [Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)

Comment: The greater problem is that <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script> breaks funcitonality

Comment: <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script> and $('.home .et_pb_more_button').on('click',function() {
ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'click', 'case study');
}); work and will fire, but it breaks the functionality. If I remove <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script> functionality returns, but events dont fire. So...make me think <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script> is the problem.

Comment: Open up your browsers' development console and look if there are errors thrown. You are running circles and your statements do not help identifying the problem at all. Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask